# Turning Columns Into Rows Using SQL Server 2012+ AND T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns 1 row:

```
SELECT fy.Id ,
       fy.FirstStart ,
       fy.SecondStart ,
       fy.ThirdStart ,
       fy.FourthStart

FROM dbo.FiscalYears fy
WHERE [Year] = 2017
```

This is the result:

```
| Id | FirstStart | SecondStart | ThirdStart | FourthStart |
|----|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|
| 5  | 2016-04-03 | 2016-07-03  | 2016-10-02 | 2017-01-01  |
```

I'd like to turn this into:

```
| Name        | Date       |
|-------------|------------|
| FirstStart  | 2016-04-03 |
| SecondStart | 2016-07-03 |
| ThirdStart  | 2016-10-02 |
| FourthStart | 2017-01-01 |
```

I've looked at other questions similiar to this that use a PIVOT in a subquery but I'm not able to figure it out.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, FirstStart, SecondStart, ThirdStart, FourthStart
    FROM dbo.FiscalYears
) fy
UNPIVOT
(Date FOR Name IN (FirstStart, SecondStart, ThirdStart, FourthStart)) AS t
```

Comment: Nailed it.  Thank you.